# Underlining text in Google Earth Engine panel

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, css

I am currently writing a code for an app in which I would like to underline some text. However, looking at the [ui.Panel.style](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-panel-style) options there is none which allows underlining the text.

It says that style properties behave like their CSS counterparts, but the CSS property for underlining is

```
text-decoration: underline
```

But this returns an error on GEE (Invalid parameter for layout manager). I tried textDecoration just in case but it didn't work either. Is it even possible to underline text? Or is this a dead end?

Here is an example:

```
 var panel = ui.Panel();
  panel.style().set({
    width: '25%',
    position: 'bottom-right',
    maxHeight: '80%'
  });
  
Map.add(panel);

var linkLabel = ui.Label('Example',{fontSize: '12.5px'/* other properties go here*/}).setUrl('http://www.example.com/');
var linkPanel = ui.Panel([linkLabel]);

panel.add(linkPanel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no way to do underline yet.

Comment: I just submitted a fix for this.  It should be available next week.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use "textDecoration" to underline your label.
Here is an example:

```
//--------------
Map.add(ui.Label(
'Queries at itsakashpandey@gmail.com',{
   textDecoration: 'underline',
   position: 'bottom-right',
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   fontSize: '13px'
}));
//---------------
```